# Harmonious "Convergence"

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The [Alternating Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) is a well known convergent series.

[image: 1/1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + ...]

"Clearly", it is obvious that it converges to the natural log of 2. Or does it?

Since the series is not [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence), by simply rearranging the terms, I can make it approach anything I want. Suppose I want the series to converge to [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). All I'd have to do is this:

[image: 1/1 + 1/3 + ... + 1/65 - 1/2 + 1/67 + ... + 1/175 - 1/4]

If you didn't catch the pattern, there isn't an obvious one. Here's how it works:

1. Consider the terms of the alternating harmonic series in terms of positive and negative terms.
2. Add together just enough positive terms to exceed our target (e). (aka `sum > target`)
3. Subtract the next negative term.
4. Go back to 2.

Note that at step 2, if our `sum == target`, you should add another positive term.

From this we can define a sequence associated with each number as follows:

- Follow the algorithm above
- For each positive term, output 1.
- For each negative term, output 0.

Let's call this sequence the "Harmonious Bit Pattern" of a number. For example, the HBP of e begins as:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, <32 times>, 0, 1, 1, <54 times>, 0, 1, 1, ...
```

### Your challenge:

You will be given:

- a rational input *target* in the range [-10, 10] (note: even reaching 10 via the harmonic series takes many millions of terms). This may be a decimal (aka `1.1`) or you may take a rational directly (aka `12/100`)
- a positive `int` *n* input, specifying the number of terms of the Harmonious Bit Pattern to output.

You are expected to output the exact Harmonious Bit Pattern of the *target* to the specified number of terms. You may output space separated values, comma separated, no separation, etc; just as long as the pattern of 0s and 1s is clearly visible and is read left to right with consistent separation.

### Test Cases

```
>>> 0, 1
1
>>> 0, 2
10
>>> 0, 7
1000010
>>> 1, 10
1101011011
>>> 1.01, 3
110
>>> 1.01, 24
110101101101101101101101
>>> 2.71, 32
11111111111111111111111111111111
>>> 2.71, 144
111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>>> -9.8, 100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that since `-9.8` is so large, the first `1` that would be output is somewhere around the `149496620`th term (that was computed via floats, so the value might not be exact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Perl, 69 bytes

```
use bigrat;$s+=.5/($s>$ARGV[$_=0]?-++$n:++$p-++$_/2),print for 1..pop
```

Takes inputs as command line arguments.

**Explanation**: `bigrat` enables fractions everywhere for accurate calculations. `$s` is the current sum of terms, `$ARGV[0]` is the target value, `pop` (same as `$ARGV[1]`) represents the number of terms, `$p` and `$n` represent the positive and negative term counts. `$_` is either `1` or `0` depending on whether a positive or negative term was added.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>92</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
import Data.Ratio
f=(.h 0 1 2).take
h a p q z|a>z=0:h(a-1%q)p(q+2)z|1<2=1:h(a+1%p)(p+2)q z
```

Usage example: `f 24 1.01` -> `[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]`.

`h` builds the infinite bit pattern by carrying four parameters around: `a` is the current sum. `p` is the denominator of the next positive term, `q` for negative terms. `z` is the target number. `f` starts everything up and truncates the result to length `n`.

Edit: @Zgarb found a byte to save. Thanks!

Comment: Defining `h a p q` instead of `h p q a` saves a byte.

Comment: Should be noted that 7 bytes are spent on just trimming the infinite result list to one of length _n_. It would actually be much nicer to just give the infinite list as the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>128</s> 124 bytes

```python
from fractions import*
F=Fraction
*c,s=2,1,0
t=F(input())
for i in'x'*int(input()):w=s<=t;s+=F(w*2-1,c[w]);c[w]+=2;print(+w)
```

This makes use of Python's `Fraction` class.

```python
from fractions import* 
F=Fraction
*c,s=2,1,0                # c = [2, 1]. s = 0
                          # c is my positive/negative term counter, s is the sum
t=F(input())              # input a fraction
for i in'x'*int(input()): # Do this for for the chosen number of terms, as per the spec
  w=s<=t;                 # "w" or which one do we choose? Positive or negative?
  s+=F(w*2-1,c[w]);       # w*2-1 gives 1 if w else -1. Gives 1 if we need to add, else -1
  c[w]+=2;                # Increment the coefficient we chose
  print(+w)               # Output that. The +w coerces the bool to an int.
```

Comment: `'x'*int(input())`?